# How to change the default folder for new documents saved on my onderive?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive

For example Excel Online: I go to New select whatever template and a new spreadsheet is opened. I would expect that this file file is saved in my onedrive root folder. However, every document, spreadsheet etc. is saved in onedrive/stuff/myStuff.

A very specific folder, probably configured as default folder by me a long time ago. However, I cannot find any settings where I can change it.

Comment: select file-save as, then select the folder, Excel continues to use the last folder used until its changed.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the answer, I saved a spreadsheet into the root folder from the web app and from the desktop client